# HTML tag auto open/close/expand/quote problem

Tags: spacemacs, web-mode

I'm a novice at emacs use in general, and new to spacemacs, so I'm hoping this is just a case of missing a trick or two. I am working in a symlinked app on Mac OSX, not in the terminal.

I have a pretty much stock config of spacemacs, added a few extra layers, in evil-mode. I'm trying to do some work with HTML, using web-mode, and it isn't behaving entirely as described:

If I type `<li` I get a dropdown menu that completes words, but doesn't complete the open/close tag (is this intended behaviour, or is it supposed to complete your selection if you make one?).

If I type `<li></` it will autocomplete properly to `<li></li>`, matching indicated behaviour. I have tried setting `web-mode-tag-auto-close-style` to `2` in `dotspacemacs/userconfig ()` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402326/turning-off-automatic-tag-closing-in-emacs-web-mode) answer to allow completion at opening tag closure instead of closure tag opening (i.e. `<li>` --> `<li></li>`) but have had no luck getting it to work. Am I putting it in the wrong place or using the wrong syntax?

If I type `d/s/` as in the [example](http://web-mode.org) it results in `<d/>` instead of the indicated `<div><span>|</div></span>`. Yet if I type `d` `TAB` `s` `TAB` it produces `<d>s</d>|` and if I then scroll back to `s` and hit `TAB` again, it produces `<d><s></s></d>` I have not been able to find more detailed information about this function of web-mode, am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

## Auto-closing

I'm not sure what's going on with `(setq web-mode-tag-auto-close-style 2)`, but you can get auto-closing with `</` as you noted, and also with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key via emmet-mode (see below).

#### *Emmet-mode auto-closing*

You can get `<div>|</div>` with either

- `div`<kbd>TAB</kbd>
- `div>`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

...but not with `<div>`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

## Expanders

To get the behaviour you want with `d/s/`, you need to include the following setup code in your config:

```
(eval-after-load "web-mode"
  '(setq web-mode-enable-auto-expanding t))
```

## Emmet-mode

Note that the Spacemacs html-layer includes [emmet-mode](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode) ("zencoding") as well as web-mode, which gives you convenient shortcuts.<sup>1</sup>

<sub>**1**   The web-mode expanders will change the behaviour of emmet-mode shortcuts slightly, I doubt it will cause any problems.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`web-mode-tag-auto-close-style` got renamed to `web-mode-auto-close-style` in this commit https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/commit/c17be6c4900fdfe4e996552efc39bdff782c6585